# Renaming a Field name by accepting values from textboxes...It shows "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I am using text boxes, `textbox1` accepts the value for the existing field and `textbox2` accepts new field name. when I click on the button, the corresponding field name I entered  in `textbox1` in the d/b should change as entered in the `textbox2`.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    //str = "sp_RENAME 'book.author','Au_Name','COLUMN'";

    str = "sp_RENAME 'book.'" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','COLUMN'";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog= Library;Integrated Security=true");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    //("SELECT * FROM IMSLogin WHERE Uname = '" + Uname + "' AND PWD= '" + pwd + "'", con)
}
```

Thanks Very much,

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

The first and most obvious problem is that user input is sent directly to the db.

The second problem, which may solve your question, is the single quotation behing `sp_rename 'book.`

From comment: Replace

```
str = "sp_RENAME 'book.'" + TextBox1.Text
```

with

```
str = "sp_RENAME 'book." + TextBox1.Text
```

(and maybe [add some checks](http://xkcd.com/327/) on the content of TextBox1.Text)

Comment: but the right syntax is sp_RENAME 'tablename.columnname', 'new field name', 'COLUMN' That's y i used the single quotes before that

Comment: Yes, but what you'd execute is sp_rename 'table.'column' instead of it. Replace "str = "sp_RENAME 'book.'" + TextBox1.Text " with "str = "sp_RENAME 'book." + TextBox1.Text "

Comment: I can't get the formatting in the comment straight - I've updated the answer... hope it helps

Comment: Thank you once again...I got the answer too and i thought i wanted to give the quote to accept the value from textbox1...